# Выгрузка реестра запрещенных сайтов Роскомнадора

Tags: debian

Добрый день.
Появилась проблема в выгрузке реестра запрещенных сайтов.
Всё стабильно выгружалось, но в один момент остановилось и всё.
В маршрутизаторе Микротик вижу, что скрипт отправляет запрос, но ответа не получает, в итоге выбрасывает ошибку timeout.

Сразу хочу сказать, что скрипт исправно работал целый год и его код не менялся.
И вот 4 октября нынешнего года что то изменилось.

Буду признателен в любой помощи.

Comment: У вас срок действия квалифицированной электронной подписи случайно не истек ? Ее как раз на 1 год дают ... Вообще РКН возвращает сообщения об ошибках если что не так, скрипт по хорошему их должен куда нибудь писать, что бы понять что происходит

Comment: Электронную подпись только обновили и после этого он пару дней выгружал и только потом перестал. Ошибку возвращает только ту, что превышен порог ожидания ответа.

Comment: Надо по шагам разбирать. сначала подписывается запрос, потом запрос отправляется. В ответ уже приходит первый код завершения, надо убедится что запрос принят. Потом, через пару минут, пытаемся получить ответ, тут может приходить ошибка "ответ еще не готов". делаем несколько попыток. Надо понять на какой именно стадии ошибка и какая, вернувшаяся от РКН или может сам запрос на шлюз не проходит из за недоступности интернета на машине, например

Comment: Так же в ответ на запрос приходит ключ для проверки, можно этот ключ руками вбить на портале реестра и посмотреть что он отвечает

Comment: Запрос подписывается, подписанный xml файл создается и отправляется. Интернет на машине доступен.DNS работает. В ручном режиме проверял, всё выгружается.

Comment: Останавливается на этой строчке кода: client = suds.client.Client("http://vigruzki.rkn.gov.ru/services/OperatorRequest/?wsdl");

Comment: Хм. но это же просто получение SOAP схемы для работы сервиса ... Т.е. там шлется HTTP запрос и обратно приходит небольшая XML с описанием. Попробуйте с машины на которй скрипт руками выполнить `wget` с этой ссылкой и посмотреть приходит ли xml. Если не приходит - значит какие то проблемы с прохождением этого запроса в интернет. Ну либо РКН почему то именно вашему IP не отвечает, что мягко говоря странно

Comment: Подключение к vigruzki.rkn.gov.ru (vigruzki.rkn.gov.ru)|46.61.232.10|:80...

Comment: На этом процесс останавливается.

Comment: А какая может быть проблема у Debian, что он не может до ресурса достучаться? Вроде DNS отработал.

Comment: Ну да, DNS отработал, IP правильный. надо смотреть tcpdump на исходящем интерфейсе `tcpdump -n -i ethX host 46.61.232.10` уходят ли запросы на подключение. дальше по хорошему то же самое на промежуточных шлюзах в интернет проверить. попробовать с других машин в вашей же сети зайти

Comment: Огромное спасибо, с проблемой разобрался.